# It is possible to do a SELECT MIN(DATE) searching in 2 or more columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I have a table which have 2 columns of dates, and I want to look for the closest date in the future (Select min()?) searching in both columns, is that possible?

For example, if I have `column1=23/11/2014` and `column2=22/11/2014`, in the same row, I want get `22/11/2014`

I hope it is clear enough, ask me if it doesn't.

Greetings.

Comment: Your question title says "searching in 2 or more tables" but the text says "2 columns" - which is it, multiple tables or columns?

Comment: @Tony Thanks for your appreciation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a single table use [CASE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm)

```
SELECT CASE column1 < column2 
           THEN column1
           ELSE column2
       END mindate 
  FROM yourtable
```

If you have the date column in multiple tables, just replace `yourtable` with your tables `JOIN`ed together

Answer (score 1):

This is what the `least()` function is for:

```
select least(column_1, column_2) 
from your_table;
```

`min()` is an aggregate function that operates on a single column but multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
select min(date) from(
 select a.date date from table1 a
 union
 select b.date2 date from table1 b
)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, throw an ORA-00909 error: invalid number of arguments.